# Compare two list<int> without using Contains keyword

Tags: linq

```
List<int> list1= new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
List<int> list2 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
var test= list1.where(x=>x.Contains(list2)).ToList();
```

its not working for me..

I dont want to use Except() also..

what Can I use to know list1 values having in list2

Comment: both are List<int>

Comment: you want to check if all of items in list1 is also in list2 OR if any of items in list1 is in list2?

Comment: any one item. Contains will check either value exists or not..rit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Intersect`

```
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
    var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var test  = list1.Intersect(list2); //1.2.3.4
}
```

[image]

---

new question :

> That good one. Actually my requriement is like this ....... var getdata =Data2 .Where(x => Data1.prop2.Contains(x.prop2)) .Select(x => new { prop1= x.prop1, prop3 = x.prop3 }) .ToList();... here both data1.prop2 and x.prop2 are List and getting at x.prop2 in second line of code. error is Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to long

e.g

[image]

because cotains parameter is Enumrable not long so system throw the error.
you can use `Intersect` and `Any` to slove it.

demo code :

```
void Main()
{
    var Data2 = new[]{
        new MyClass()
        {
            prop1 = "prop1",
            prop2 = new List<long>() {1,2,3,4,5},
            prop3 = "prop3"
        }
    };
    var Data1 = new MyClass()
    {
        prop2 = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    };

    var getdata = Data2.Where(x => Data1.prop2.Intersect(x.prop2).Any())
        .Select(x => new { prop1= x.prop1, prop3 = x.prop3 }) .ToList();
    ; 
}

class MyClass
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public List<long> prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That good one. Actually my requriement is  like this .......

         var getdata =Data2
            .Where(x => Data1.prop2.Contains(x.prop2))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                prop1= x.prop1,
                prop3 = x.prop3
            })
            .ToList();... here both data1.prop2 and x.prop2 are List<long> and getting at x.prop2 in second line of code. error is Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<long> to long

Comment: Thank you..this works perfect for me.. but if prop2 list items are not equal then it will not select any items..rit?

Comment: @bmdprasad yes,it'll get nothing

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Where()` wrong I think. If you use this method on list of ints your `x` is `int`. `int` has no `Contains` method. You could do it like 
`var test= list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x)).ToList();`